# How to display Activity when the screen is locked?

Tags: android, locking, screen

My application is launched on car docking event, I want to wake up phone (done by system) and unlock screen when I plug my device.

Is it posssible ?

Comment: I hope it is not, I wouldn't want my phone to unlock anytime! (I could dial by mistake...)

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this to "How to display my activity when the screen is locked", as you can't "unlock" the device programatically in android...

Comment: Indeed, as SrikeForceZero explains, you cannot "unlock" the device programatically.  What the answers below that seem to suggest you can are really doing is showing how you can make a specific Activity *interactive* **while the device, overall, remains locked**.

Answer (score 44):

I'm use for upping activity to top level

```
    private Window wind;
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    /******block is needed to raise the application if the lock is*********/
    wind = this.getWindow();
    wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    /* ^^^^^^^block is needed to raise the application if the lock is*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly, even if I place it on OnCreate.

Comment: I don't know. Please, test this method and tell us!

Comment: Does not work on KitKat. Screen lights up but activity does not show until user unlock the screen.

Answer (score 21):

Use Activity.getWindow() to get the window of your activity; use Window.addFlags() to add whichever of the following flags in WindowManager.LayoutParams that you desire: [FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD), [FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED), [FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)

This is how the standard car dock (and desk dock) app implements this behavior.

Comment: cool it works, but these flags only available on sdk version 5 and higher :(

Comment: found universal approach, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up/4541982#4541982

Comment: primarily can't get it working on ICS as a service.  I even tried to create an activity that does this

Comment: At this point API 5 and higher has about 99% of the market.  I see no reason to use tricks when you can just use these flags.

Comment: Somehow for me this does not work. I added the flags in onCreate() of my activity, which is called by my BroadcastReceiver, upon an alarm incoming, set by AlarmManager. The onCreate is called, the flags are set but the phone remains black and locked.

Comment: @Yar did you end up getting this to work? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to use `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` only for phones which do not have security enabled locks like pattern lock.

`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` will only bring your current Activity on the top, if user tries to move elsewhere, he will have to unlock the screen.

Alternatively, you can add permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

And, in your activity on create:

```
KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("abc");
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Answer (score 4):

When using a lock pattern or a pin entry I needed to add the following as well because the screen turned off in less than 5 seconds:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```