# Unlock Android phone programmatically?

Tags: android, locking, screen, unlock

I want to write the code on how to unlock the Android Phone programmatically.

I want lock or unlock the phone when the user taps the proximity sensor.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{   

    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF";
    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);

        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, theFilter);
        System.out.println("inside increate");
        myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                    System.out.println("phone locked*****");                
            }

        };   

    }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How my app can unlock screen programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter);
            System.out.println("BROADcast receiver registered****");
    }

     private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("phone locked"); 

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

An Alternative solution... try this to unlock the screen..