# How to unlock device when its locked after certain time,programmatically?

Tags: android

How to unlock device when its locked after certain amount of time,programmatically?

I want to trigger an daemon thread in background to unlock the device if its locked, after x interval of time in android 4x.

Is this doable programmatically?

Regards

Comment: Refer this--->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android

Comment: and this too--->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004720/unlock-android-phone-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iwashisoft.autounlock) in the market that can do this, so my guess would be: yes

EDIT: [How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

Comment: i got this helpful link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html  this might help.But i was thinking, what if device is password enabled locked?

Comment: It only works when there is no password. Google isn't going to put anything into android that completely circumvents the security :D