# Android screen lock/ unlock programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on a app in which I have to lock and unlock the screen programmatically. Kindly help ! I have no any idea how to develop this type of functionality which support each version of Android OS.

Comment: Check out this post. It may help you.
[Lock/Unlock Screen][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9193501/1177482

Comment: check https://github.com/amirarcane/lock-screen

Answer (score 29):

To Unlock

```java
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock"); 
kl.disableKeyguard(); 

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                 | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                 | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: worked for me. but deprecated method warnings appear.

Comment: Worked like Zalo app, Viber app ... Really good.

Comment: @Barend Not working on Android 4.4 also What should I do to lock the device?

Comment: Both are depreciated.

Comment: Does not work with encrypted device running marshmallow, but worked on non-Encrypted device running lollipop.

Comment: Doesn't work on Nougat (7.0) with secure screen lock.

Comment: Very very nice.

Comment: On Android 7.1.1 (OnePlus 3) it sets screen on but doesn't disable (fingerprint protected) screen guard

Answer (score 12):

This link might help you solve your Problem :

[Unlock and Lock Programmatically](http://musicm122.blogspot.in/2011/10/locking-and-unlocking-android-phone.html)

```
//Get the window from the context    
WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);   

//Unlock
Window window = getWindow();  
window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  

//Lock device  
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: With short content in your link, you can paste here in case that page die.

Comment: @Amit PL check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html)

Comment: This unlock does not work on 4.4.4, the other answer worked. Though with tons of depreciated calls.

Comment: non of these answer work for 4.4