# App Lock button for IOS and android

Tags: java, android, ios

So I have been searching for a while and I would just like to know how to make an app lock or a phone lock with a press of a button. I want to install a custom button to lock my phone instead of using the phone lock button. I want to make my own custom program to do this.
I have researched many places but I cant find anything.

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The API for locking the phone is not public in iOS. Hence, there is no way you can achieve this in iOS.

For Android, have a look at this,
[How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a way to make your own custom phone lock button. In iOS it is not possible but if you want to do that in android just look this URL:
http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-home-screen-widget-temperature.html