# Wake up device programmatically

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, unlock

I want to wake up and unlock a device. Then, I'd like show an activity when the user has new message from `Firebase`.

I wrote this on `onResume()` method:

```
window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

This works for devices with API > 19. The problem is that in `KitKat`, it either does nothing or it wakes up the screen but doesn't unlock the device.

Also I set the right permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Also in `MyFirebaseMessagingService.class`, I'm starting an activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as flag.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: check this link for unlock device via code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found it. I just add that piece of code and it worked

```
KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("abc");
lock.disableKeyguard();
```