# Launching Android app with physical buttons when screen is locked

Tags: android, launch, screen-lock

Can I launch my android app when the screen is locked, with the device's physical side buttons (a combination of them is also acceptable)?

Comment: Launching  (starting) a app a this point sounds like a catch22 for me, because any program that should unlock the screen, has to be activated a first, for that you have to unlock the screen and start it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for unlocking the screen when the app is running, I would look into tihs -> [How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically#14352807)

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to launch the app when the screen is locked...