# How Do I Make The Phone Go To Sleep?

Tags: java, android

I have an application and instead of keeping the screen on, once the app runs I want the screen to go dark. How do I do this? I know that to make the screen stay on I do this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But I cannot find out how to make the screen go dark.

Comment: u mean low brightness......

Comment: No I mean like the screen is off where you have to tap the button once to be on the lock screen

Comment: when u pressed button u wont to go to lock screen right

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget

Answer (score 0):

check this
http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html

OR Try this one

```
WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);   

//Lock device  
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM .lockNow();
```

Comment: What do I use for context?

Comment: No need for getApplicationContext, the above Context is enough