# Lockscreen in Android Things

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-things

I need to show a lockscreen after 15 seconds of user inactivity. In my project I use `ViewPager` with three pages.

How can I check for inactive user action in all the three pages and all the elements on this pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a timer that shows a lockscreen after 15 secs of inactivity and zero its timing in the [`Activity`'s `onUserInteraction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserInteraction()) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); //Get the context 

Window window = getWindow();  
window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  //Unlock the screen

DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE); //Lock the screen
```

**Note** : you may need reference to an activity that can communicate with window.

check this link : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)

Use handler for time :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // write you code 
           }
        }, 15000;//15sec
```