# How to lock/unlock phone programmatically : Android

Tags: android, keyguard

In my application, I need to lock and unlock phone. I searched for it, I found many answers, I tried them but no one is working.

I need to unlock phone on `onCreate()` and lock phone again while I'm finishing my activity.

Do you guys know any method to do the same?

Thanks friends.

**EDIT:**

Some links, that I have tried are:

[How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

[Android screen lock/ unlock programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723185/android-screen-lock-unlock-programatically)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/BOLjJTMO4zE

In my application I'm scheduling a task using `AlarmManager` and then enabling the phone lock. My activity is getting started on scheduled time but it not unlocking my phone. when I'm unlocking my phone manually running activity is getting appeared

Comment: Which answers did you try so we know not to suggest them?

Comment: "no one is working" is not a useful description of your symptoms. Please explain *completely and precisely* what you have tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: @BladeOrz: I have added some of visited pages links

Comment: @CommonWare: I have added a little description about my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

on `BroadcastReceiver` set up the `wakelock` and in the `activity`

**Do This:**

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

import following

```
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
```

Comment: This somehow seems to work, and my application is brought to the front.... event though no sim card pin has been entered.
I just somehow think that you will not be able to access any phone or data capabilities. I will let you know if this is the case...

Comment: Jip, confirmed. So you will not have access to the sim card functionality. So if you want to bypass entering the pin and fire up your app, this works great ... as long as the user doesn't minimize or close the app, cause then you're back at the login screen.

Answer (score 7):

As of API 27, `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` were deprecated. Instead use this in the `Manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:turnScreenOn="true"
    android:showWhenLocked="true"/>
```

Or, for general usage, in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
    } else {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);


        }
```

Comment: `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` was deprecated in API 26 or 27.