# authenticate user based on device lock

Tags: android, security, authentication, passwords, password-protection

I wrote an android app and I want to use device lock method for opening it. for example if user set a finger print lock for his/her device I want to use that method for opening my app instead of creating new password and force user to remember it.

Comment: it works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456456/use-screen-lock-in-my-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use screen lock in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456456/use-screen-lock-in-my-app)