# How to use android default lock screen to unlock screen on an intent fired

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I want to put password on device switch off in one of my application  ,When I want to switch off my device it ask for password ,I want to use default lock screen of android for this. Is there any way to use this.I have found some links [How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)
[How to lock/unlock phone programmatically : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923992/how-to-lock-unlock-phone-programmatically-android) but those are used to unlock programmatically

Comment: Did you find a way of unlocking the screen?

Comment: @nhenrique I have not found any solution to this