# Is it possible, using admin priviledge or similar permission, to fully unlock the device?

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard

### Background

[**Smart Lock**](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-use-android-smart-lock/) feature allows to fully unlock the device under certain conditions, such as GPS location, connected Bluetooth, etc...

### The problem

I'd like to make an app that does that, with other special conditions.

Given user's approval, is it possible to completely unlock the lock screen, even if it has a password, so that the user will continue as if he unlocked the device by himself?

### What I've found

I know it's probably possible using accessibility service, to mimic user actions of entering the code or drawing the pattern.

There is probably a way to temporarily disable the lock screen, by using keyguard API (written [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923992/how-to-lock-unlock-phone-programmatically-android) for example), but as I've read, those are deprecated and might not work on some devices and Android versions. I guess it also requires to have a foreground service for it to continue staying on this state.

### The questions

Is there a better way? Is there a way to unlock the device, just like Smart Lock feature?

If so, how?

Is it true the Keyguard API is not recommended? What is there to worry about when using it? Or maybe it's completely safe to use, and can be used to fully unlock?

Comment: have look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31067114/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar Those solutions seem to be about a temporary unlock, of having the current app in the foreground (useful for alarm clock apps, for example). Are you sure they are about full unlock, like on Smart-Lock feature?

Comment: no i am not sure much about this, i just suggested that given link is may be  useful for you..thanks!!

Comment: @HemantParmar Well I wrote that this is what I've found. I'm almost certain this is also what I've read...