# how to bring up lock screen in android?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I want to bring up the lock screen of the device if a button is clicked. I searched a lot and know that could be done by `DevicePolicyManager` but don't know how to do that. I also found lots of examples but neither of them brought up the lock screen(with no error)(e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723185/android-screen-lock-unlock-programatically) or [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html))
how to lock device using `DevicePolicyManager`?

Comment: //Lock device
  DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
  mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

Comment: please add ur code to show what all u tried. Surely u r doing some mistake ..

Comment: @user123 I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12723269/1986618

Comment: @user123 what is the mistake?

Comment: You should add  your complete activity code from where the button is being clicked

Comment: @user12 OK, I will do that in hours! thanx for your attention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also found lots of examples but neither of them brought up the lock screen(with no error)(e.g. this or this)

That second link should work. It looks similar to [my LockMeNow sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/LockMeNow), which I know works, as I just demonstrated it in a training class two days ago.

You need to implement a `DeviceAdminReceiver` whose manifest entry contains a `<meta-data>` link to a policy document that says that you want the ability to `<force-lock />` the device.

Then, the *user* needs to agree to this, by going into Settings > Security > Device Administrators and enable your app as a device administrator. There is code in both my sample and the one that you linked to that contains code that checks to see if the app is a device administrator, and if not leads the user into Settings to go enable it.

Once that is done, you can obtain a `DevicePolicyManager` and call `lockNow()`.

Comment: thanks, your code works well. but the only bad thing is this that it turns off the screen, how to prevent this happening? I mean directly bring up the lock screen?

Comment: @Soheil: I'm not aware of a way to do that, sorry.