# How do I force unlock screen to show up?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to achieve "Touch again to open" when clicking on a notification on lock screen. But I don't seem to get my head around how to actually get the screen unlock view to show up? Is there an intent or something to broadcast for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might help :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18547462/1393623

Comment: No, I don't think so. I definitely don't wonna to do that. "Then, the user needs to agree to this, by going into Settings > Security > Device Administrators ". This is not the the solution.

Comment: I am not aware of any other methods which allow us to open the lock screen without getting the device admin permission. Please update if you find anything on this. :)

Comment: I don't want to bypass the key. I want the lock scree to show up as my question says.

Comment: @peuhse Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call requestDismissKeyguard() method from KeyguardManager class:

```
KeyguardManager mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

if (mKeyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) {
  mKeyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, new KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDismissSucceeded() {
      super.onDismissSucceeded();
      //TODO
    }
  });
}
```