# How Do I Make The Phone Go To Lock Screen?

Tags: android

I have an app, that after I finish I want the app to go to the lock screen, however I am unable to do so. How can I do this?`

```
//Lock screen
finish();
```

Comment: you can look at this post too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically

Comment: Angel I looked into it and I found this:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723185/android-screen-lock-unlock-programmatically/12723269#12723269

Comment: However, Context is not working for me. How Do I make context work?

Comment: if you are calling it from the Activity class, just remove Context and use getSystemService(...); if you are calling from the Fragment class, use getContext().getSystemService(...)