# Android - Wake Up and Unlock Device

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, keyguard

**Application description:**
The application is intended as a safety program for a specific client (not to be deployed publicly). When the application has not detected movement for a certain period of time, the application should sound an alarm and bring itself to the foreground if it is in the background or the device is asleep.

**The problem:**
In the event the device is asleep and locked, we need to wake up and unlock the device. Using various techniques found here on SO and other places, we've been able to (partially) wake and unlock the device, however this ONLY behaves properly when the device is physically plugged in to a computer. If the device is sitting by itself unplugged, and we test the wake-unlock, nothing happens; the device seems to remain asleep, and the application seems to do nothing at all (no alarm).

I have used [this post about using PowerManager and KeyguardManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179932/877472), and [this post using window flags.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9193501/877472)

Here is the code presently used to wake the device:

```
public void wakeDevice() {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            getWindow().addFlags(
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);                
        }
    });
}
```

From the comments and posts on some of the other SO questions I've seen / used, it seems as though the PowerManager / KeyguardManager code should have done the trick. Again, as I said before, it does technically work while the device is plugged in via USB to the dev machine, but does absolutely nothing while the device is separated.

Also note this is our first Android application, and so are fully aware we might be completely off on what we are trying to do. Any suggestions are welcome.

So in short, given the code above, why does the device behave so differently based on whether it is plugged in, and what should we change in order to wake and unlock the device as described? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I solved the issue. The reason we observed different behaviour when the device was plugged in via USB was because the device's CPU was not going to sleep. I assume this is either a result of the debug mode setting, or simply how it behaves when plugged in to a computer since the power-saving feature of CPU-sleeping would be irrelevant. Obviously, when the device is not plugged in, the CPU would happily take a nap, and while we did observe the application randomly running (it would wake itself up at random times), the timing would be inconsistent. I further assume this is because the few CPU cycles that occurred are allocated sparingly, and our application would be given very few cycles at "random" times.

So our solution was to grab a partial wake lock when the device goes into the background (which is done in the `onPause` method), and release the lock in the `onResume` method. This seems to prevent the CPU from sleeping. We continue to use the full wake lock and keyguard disable to wake the device when we need to. Using the partial wake lock seems to keep the CPU from sleeping, and the device does appear to wake up properly when expected. Here is our updated code, in case anyone comes across this issue:

```
// Called from onCreate
protected void createWakeLocks(){
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    fullWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");
    partialWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Loneworker - PARTIAL WAKE LOCK");
}

// Called implicitly when device is about to sleep or application is backgrounded
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    partialWakeLock.acquire();
}

// Called implicitly when device is about to wake up or foregrounded
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(fullWakeLock.isHeld()){
        fullWakeLock.release();
    }
    if(partialWakeLock.isHeld()){
        partialWakeLock.release();
    }
}

// Called whenever we need to wake up the device
public void wakeDevice() {
    fullWakeLock.acquire();

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
}
```

Comment: Do you need a super.onPause() call added at the top of the onPause() method?  Was getting crashes when this was excluded.

Comment: @CharlieSeligman Ah yes, forgot to add that. Will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Teeg not sure who downvoted you but it certainly wasnt me... implemented this last night on my Light Alarm app and it worked a treat this morning - all went off correctly. Thank you VERY much for this solution! +1 on question and answer.

Comment: @CharlieSeligman Cool man, thanks a lot. Didn't think it was you but didn't know who or why. I'm glad it worked for you as well. Also glad I wasn't the only one in the world who struggled with this issue.

Comment: Awesome , After so long search , hit and try I finally got the perfect solution , cheers to you man

Comment: @PaulRichter  i have put an alarm as soon as alarm fires i want to unlock device and want to show my apps activity ? will i use same method ? where will i  call wakeDevice ?

Comment: @ErumHannan (Sorry for the delay) Yes it sounds like you would use the same method as described here. You would probably call `wakeDevice` from the callback or method that is executed when the alarm's timeout has elapsed (depends how you're doing that).

Comment: @PaulRichter I tried this code and it works for me halfly - i.e. activity send to BroadcastReceiver shows, but only for one second and then finishes for no reason. Here's the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591199/waking-up-device-do-not-work

Comment: @jeand'arme Looks like you've solved the problem. I didn't see anything you were doing all that different that would have caused that the odd 1 second wake-sleep. I guess it was a flag issue in the end, judging from your answer.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Greetings from Canada. I'm glad this helped.

Comment: Why do you have 2 kinds of wakelock on this code? Are they needed both to run this? I can't see how those two connect.

Comment: @neonWarge Its been a very long time since I worked with this stuff, but as far as I know, they're both necessary in this case. Partial lock keeps the cpu running even when the device is supposed to be asleep, full lock lets you illuminate and unlock the screen.

Comment: @paulrichter good stuff. Also answered my age old doubt about a voice activation app that would run during my USB debugging and while it was charging, but never when left alone! But now will get back and crack it. ;-)

Comment: Working in normal mode, But din't work when device lock with password/pattern/fingerprint security. Any idea how can i done with this?

Comment: @RRR_1173 Unfortunately, its been so long since I worked with this, I can't even guess how to solve that. Maybe there's some type manager that bypasses the security...but that seems unlikely and unsafe. Sorry.