# Android: Re-open app after X minutes of idling?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I need my app to open itself back up after a certain amount of minutes that the device has been idle. In other words, instead of the device going into sleep mode and going to a black screen, my app will open back up (assuming it's running in the background). Think of it as an "idle screen" app.

It's fairly simple in theory, but I just can't figure out if it's even possible.

Comment: Have you looked at [Wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)?  Also, this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14757159/3033053) may be helpful

Comment: @silencedmessage Thanks, but that's for keeping an Android device on, and/or waking up the device at a later date. Not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some service running, you can reopen the application by using one of the methods described  here [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: Thank you! Now I've figured out half my problem, but I still need to detect when the device has been idling for X minutes - any thoughts on how to do that?