# NullPointerException from MediaPlayer onPause() looses reference

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I get NullPointerException from MediaPlayer through onPause() method when exiting from activity. The strange thing is I get no error from LogCat - I had to do if(mp == null) Log.i(TAG, "mp is null"); and this logs to LogCat. After exiting sound is playing for coule of seconds and then stops.

This method I call from onPause():

```
void releaseThis(){

    if(mp == null) Log.i("ASD", "nie ma mediaplayera");
    if (mp != null) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        Log.i("ASD", "a tu już jest mediaplayer");
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    if(wl.isHeld()){
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

Basic architecture:

```
public class CallScreen extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;

    onCreate(){
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "My Tag");
        wl.acquire();
    Uri notification =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        playSound(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    }

    playSound(context, alert){
    (here's the beef)
    }
}
```

Log:

```
    04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.klangstudios.fakecall/com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.isHeld()' on a null object reference

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3312)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:148)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.isHeld()' on a null object reference

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen.releaseThisShit(CallScreen.java:94)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen.onPause(CallScreen.java:106)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6064)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1317)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3292)

04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.klangstudios.fakecall, PID: 32581

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.klangstudios.fakecall/com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.isHeld()' on a null object reference

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3312)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3259)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:148)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.isHeld()' on a null object reference

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen.releaseThisShit(CallScreen.java:94)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen.onPause(CallScreen.java:106)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6064)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1317)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3292)

04-13 14:55:51.658 32581 32581 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.klangstudios.fakecall, PID: 10261

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.klangstudios.fakecall/com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2995)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1336)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.klangstudios.fakecall.CallScreen.onResume(CallScreen.java:106)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1264)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6039)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2978)

04-13 15:19:15.822 10261 10261 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more

04-13 15:39:49.540 16631 16646 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb4e84e56 in tid 16646 (Binder_1)
```

Comment: firstly, use command `adb shell bugreport > log.txt` to get the log.

Comment: Done it, but I don't think that I can paste it here - it's freakin' long

Comment: just find the `NullPointerException` in the file, the log trace should be there.

Comment: there's more below that, maybe about 50 lines are related, it's a Exception stack trace, from the statck trace we can finger out which line causes the exception.

Comment: @yummy okay, looks like wl.isHeld got NPE as well.

Comment: The exception is regarding the wake lock being null, not the media player

Comment: check the answer by @TheCrafter, and MediaPlayer would also result in fatal exception, pls check where you use `play`

Comment: @yummy I use it on onCreate() as the last command and on onStart() because normal mp.start() didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. You just need delete playSound() from onCreate() and put it to onResume() since onResume() is always called before Activity get to the foreground.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

`04-13 14:55:29.934 32338 32338 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.isHeld()' on a null object reference`

If you read carefully here you can see that the problem is on `isHeld()`

Just add a check on your `wl` just like you did on `mp`.

Something like

```
if(wl != null){
    if(wl.isHeld()){
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't resolves problem. I don't understand why those two looses references if it's in one activity and variables are global.

Comment: Well according to your exception it should solve the problem. Maybe you should try posting greater part of your code. For example where you declare `wl` and `mp`

Comment: Here's more code - just don't want to make this question all about code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591199/waking-up-device-do-not-work

Comment: `private PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;` Seems to me that wl is always null! I dont see any other value assigned to it.

Comment: Forgot to include it here. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        //stop music
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
```