# Android wake up and unlock device

Tags: android

I want to create an alert application. The alert is received using GCM (GoogleCloudMessaging). Now I want to show the alert message on the screen without any actions by the user. Therefore I need to wake up the device and unlock the screen.

In the forum I found this answer (and some similar) describing how I can achieve this behaviour:
[android-wake-up-and-unlock-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741612/android-wake-up-and-unlock-device)

Reading the documentation, using `WakeLock`s seems to be deprecated: i.e.
[full_wake_lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK)

> FULL_WAKE_LOCK Added in API level 1
>
> int FULL_WAKE_LOCK
>
> This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Most applications should
>   use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will
>   be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between
>   applications and doesn't require a special permission.

In the documentation an alternative is shown using the `WindowManager`.
With help of the flags

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
```

I should be able to bring my alert message to the front without asking for the keyguard secure pattern.

My question now is:
When I want to use these flags, do I also need a `wakeLock` to wake up my device or is this done implicit by the window manager?

Comment: I simply implemented it and it seems that it works...

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Are there permissions we need to ask the user for?

Comment: all permissions I use:
<!-- Let the device vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    
<!-- Modify audio setting -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />