# Unlock screen programmatically and show activity

Tags: java, android

I have one activity and it's in foreground while screen is locked. This activity has a button, and when its pressed it should bring CALL LOG activity to the foreground, but instead I only got unlock screen activity (see pic below). But if I unlock that screen, my first activity showing is CALL LOG, but it should be visible without first unlocking screen. (see pics below)

I checked [How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically?lq=1), but its not working as it should!

Basically this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.missed_call_IV:
        //finish();
        Intent showContacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Calls.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(showContacts);
        Window w;
        w = getWindow();
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        break;
    }
}
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: you would need to either make your own activity to display the call log or prevent phone from locking the screen. `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` makes YOUR activity available while the lock screen is shown. the call log activity built into the OS does not have this flag. I don't believe there is a way to programitcally unlock the screen, since its a system UI. and it would cause a security problem if it could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use KeyGuardLock from program

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock keyguard = km.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
```

to unlock screen

```
keyguard.disableKeyguard();
```

and dont forget to lock again after you have completed task

```
keyguard.reenableKeyguard();
```

use the following permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" >
</uses-permission>
```