# Android activity popup on lockscreen

Tags: android

Ok, first time asking, I couldn't find a solution anywhere..

I'm trying to create an activity that pops up on the lockscreen, kinda like Handcent does (or even Viber, maybe? Can't remember), but I can't for the life of me find a solution that actually works, be it flags, system alert and such

So far I only managed to achieve a workaround by having a dialog themed app and unlocking the phone before showing it but that's not what I'd like to have in the final product, plus it doesn't unlock all kinds of lockscreen (based on user feedbacks, I've had reports of Handcent successfully displaying a dialog while my app can't unlock it)

Is there any tutorial or code snippet for this?

Answer (score 0):

For Unlocking the Phone programatically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically) should help.
And as you are already using the Dialog Theme, your application's "pop-up" requirements are completed.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now (except I'm using a wakelock due to a broadcastReceiver being fired first), but as I said, one of my users' phone doesn't get unlocked as he has some extra apps (he mentions "TrustGo Security" and "Google Apps Device Policy") that probably provide an extra layer of security that doesn't allow apps to bypass the lockscreen, so... any other way to do it, or should I just give up on him?