# How to unlock Android phone from service

Tags: android

How to unlock Android phone from `android.app.Service;` service when phone is in locked state?

Comment: check this question out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up/4541982#4541982

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake Android Device up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Wake Android Device up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up/4541982#4541982)