# android show activity when phone sleep

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a broadcast receiver who's job is to open an Activity. (Specifically when i receive a certain SMS).
When my phone is on and I use it, it works great.
But when my phone is on sleep mode nothing happens.
Do I need to add a code in my broadcast receiver to WAKEUP the phone and release the SCREEN LOCK (if there is) and then open the Activity?
Or is there a better solution?

This is the relevant code in the broadcast receiver onReceive function:

```
    //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
intent.putExtra("coordinates", coordinates);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073631/android-wake-phone

Comment: Yes, But maybe there was another solution.
How do i check if i need to do it or not? (If the phone is on sleep or not?)

Comment: The point is, if you use a wake lock, the phone will perform it's action regardless of if the phone is on or not.  It is specifically designed to wake the phone from a sleep state, and perform your action (so you don't check - you just know it will be performed, regardless of the phones state)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a WakeLock to accomplish this.

This particular tutorial helped me with this: http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html

and another better tutorial specifically about wakelocks: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: How do i check if i need to do it or not? (If the phone is on sleep or not?)

Comment: If you want to make sure something happens, regardless of if the phone is on or not - you will use a wake lock.  This ensures your action is performed regardless of if the phone is awake or not (so you won't need to check).  I added the link to another helpful tutorial I used.