# unlocking a screen via code in android

Tags: android, password-protection

How do I unlock phone screen when some event happens?I tried the following code but it does not unlock the screeen . By unlock I mean bypass PIN or pattern

Am using following code and its get triggered when a sms is received.

```
private void unlockScreen(Context context){
        Log.d("dialog", "unlocking screen now");
        PowerManager powermanager = ((PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        WakeLock wakeLock = powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        Window wind = DialogActivity.this.getWindow();
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


    }
```

Screen is powered on but the user has to enter PIN/pattern.How do I get over it?

Comment: You don't!  Write a custom ROM.  What would be the point of a lock pattern or PIN if the OS allowed 3rd party apps to bypass it?

Comment: I think that this would be a huge security problem.  I would probably place money on you can't do this.  I only say this because someone could build a stealth app to unlock the screen when an in coming command came in or something.

Comment: The short: You can't get over it. It would raise a huge security issue otherwise if an app could be able to bypass the unlock screen.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073631/android-wake-unlock-phone

Comment: if we cant then how does our phone gets automaticaly unlocked when there is a incoming call?

Comment: because the service montioring for a call is probaly running as root also that has access to device management.

Comment: I dont want to permanently bypass keyguard, just for that moment .For example when a alarm is raised (eg wake up alarm) i can dismiss /snooze it whithot unlocking screen .How??I want to achive the  same behaviour.I want start a dialog which should be on top on locked screen. I can click button on dialog without unlocking .Is this possible?

Comment: @ObieMD5 can u plz reply to my previous comment?

Comment: What comment? you asked about incoming calls.  I answered it with the one below that.

Comment: @ObieMD5 asked a sperate question for this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866419/how-to-start-a-dialog-like-alarm-dimiss-snooze-that-can-be-clicked-without-un

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the android API Site for `disableKeyguard()`:

> Disable the keyguard from showing. If the keyguard is currently
>   showing, hide it. The keyguard will be prevented from showing again
>   until reenableKeyguard() is called. A good place to call this is from
>   onResume() **Note: This call has no effect while any DevicePolicyManager
>   is enabled that requires a password.**

Based off that bolded statement I would probably say that you cannot do that without a password.  The only way passed that is if you had yourself(app) added to the phone as a device admin, then you could control that from your device admin application of removing the password, wiping it etc.

Source : [KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html)   &  [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html)

**EDIT**

I found the source code of the [`LockPatternUtils`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java#LockPatternUtils)  (I know it is from older version, but I doubt it has changed much) that is in part pattern locks and it has DevicePolicyManager all over it.  I believe it has an internal service running as root in the system that does all the work. So without being a device admin, you do not even have authority to unlock the phone when it has a security setting for it.

Comment: I dont want to permanently bypass keyguard, just for that moment .For example when a alarm is raised (eg wake up alarm) i can dismiss /snooze it whithot unlocking screen .How??I want to achive the  same behaviour.I start a dialog which should be on top on locked screen.Is this possible?

Comment: Ask another question on SO with the question that states "How do add an event to the lockscreen such as an alarm with the ability to dismiss/snooze without unlocking the screen.  My thoughts on it is you have to create a widget that can be displayed on the lockscreen but I cannot answer that question.  Best bet is to ask that question in a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866419/how-to-start-a-dialog-like-alarm-dimiss-snooze-that-can-be-clicked-without-un

Comment: @user93796 please mark the question as answered so others will see this as the correct answer. Thank you and good luck on your other quesiton.