# How to start a dialog without unlocking the screen? Is it still possible? Android

Tags: android

I was trying to make an app that is like a bullitin board, however my goal was to add the bulletin message on the lockscreen so that the user doesn't need to unlock the phone, it just needs to swipe away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of :[How to start a dialog (like alarm dimiss /snooze) that can be clicked without unlocking the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866419/how-to-start-a-dialog-like-alarm-dimiss-snooze-that-can-be-clicked-without-un)

Comment: The post is like 3 years ago, and there's a lot of new updates. I am asking if it is still possible to run a dialog in the lockscreen.