# Can android and iOS APP run in background?

Tags: android, ios

Can APP send device data(e.g. accelerometer gyroscope proximity sensor) to the server in the background?

Comment: Did you try to google "android background process"?

Comment: Please do some research before asking here.. !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sensor listening when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093572/android-sensor-listening-when-app-in-background)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Next time I'll do more research before I ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send data in background. In Android, you need to use a service for that type of application. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093572/android-sensor-listening-when-app-in-background) you can find a more complet answer.

But be careful with that. It is not a good practice because running the sensors continuously like that would drain the battery quickly.

Comment: Thank you for comment. So just Android can do this, right?

Comment: Both Android and iOS can do this! I just give you a Android example because I am more used to it :)