# Android activity unlocking screen

Tags: android, android-activity, flags, android-windowmanager, unlock

I'm trying to add an `Activity` that makes a locked screen unlock and shows an `Activity`. Everything works except the unlocking of the screen. The `Activity` starts but the screen stays off. But I need the screen to go on the same time `Activity` starts.

I'm using the following code:

```
public void vibrate() {
    if ((deltaX > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaY > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaZ > vibrateThreshold)) {

            //http://www.androidauthority.com/android-7-0-features-673002/

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!")
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            alarmIntent.setClass(this, test.class);
            alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            this.startActivity(alarmIntent);

            new CountDownTimer(25000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                }
            public void onFinish() {
            }
            }.start();
    }
}
```

In my **AndroidManifest** I have the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [KeyguardManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)

Example:

```
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardLock = ((KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).newKeyguardLock("TAG");

keyguardLock.disableKeyguard(); // to unlock the device
keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard(); // to lock the device, only works if your application called .disableKeyguard before
```

The permission needed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

To wake up the device:

```
// Called from onCreate
protected void createWakeLocks(){
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    fullWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");
    partialWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Loneworker - PARTIAL WAKE LOCK");
}

// Called implicitly when device is about to sleep or application is backgrounded
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    partialWakeLock.acquire();
}

// Called implicitly when device is about to wake up or foregrounded
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(fullWakeLock.isHeld()){
        fullWakeLock.release();
    }
    if(partialWakeLock.isHeld()){
        partialWakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Source: [Android - Wake Up and Unlock Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741612/android-wake-up-and-unlock-device)
Another link: [Android: Wake & unlock phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073631/android-wake-unlock-phone)

Answer (score 1):

**Snippet of How to unlock and lock a screen:**

```
//Get the window from the context    
WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);   

//Unlock
Window window = getWindow();  
window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  

//Lock device  
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```