# How to wake a phone without pressing power button

Tags: android

Anybody know that how to wake a phone with any action but  without pressing power button or any hard-key and  in android programmatically..

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wake Android Device up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up)

Answer (score 4):

Yo can create a wakelock using these two flags

```
PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wake");
wakeLock .acquire();
```

This will turn the device to the lockscreen.

Use these flags to get past the lockscreen:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: @Rotemimz: I am doing application to unlock screen using accelerometer sensor. So screen will unlock by shaking. but problem is user should first press anykey then shake then screen will lock. I want to avoid pressing key. how to avoid it..