# Wake lock on receiving pushnotification. Is there an easy way?

Tags: android, push-notification, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I've followed android-hive's guide on push-notifications. And I've done my own app and implemented the necessary stuff to receive a push.
 
It works just fine, I get the push and a message and everything but the thing is, I want the screen to just light up when I get a push. Even in the original androidhive-code wake-lock didn't work for me. There must be some easy way to just make the screen wake up when i get a new push-notification right?

Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up