# Do tasks when device wakes up

Tags: android, screen

I'm have a widget that is being updated from a service. When the user then turn off the screen, the service stops and won't start to update the widget again when the user wake up the device. So on to my question, is there some way to "restart" the service when the user wake up the device? I know I can keep the service keep going when the screen is locked, but I think it would drain to much battery then... I have google'd alot but haven't found anything...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Okey, this is strange! Now somehow it does that automatically, so it's working now! Thanks anyway!

EDIT 2: Or, now I don't really think it's the screen lock that stops the service, cause it just sometimes stops randomly without crashdialog when I use the phone... Anyone know how I should do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a widget it usually doesn't make sense to keep a service running all the time, you usually update the widget periodically.

The easiest way to do this and to be battery efficient is to schedule an intent using `AlarmManager` and [setAlarmInexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour. These alarms are more power-efficient than the strict recurrences supplied by setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent), since the system can adjust alarms' phase to cause them to fire simultaneously, avoiding waking the device from sleep more than necessary.

The intent should trigger a BroadcastReceiver which in turn should trigger your service to update the widget. Using `IntentService` is usually a good choice for that.

If you need more control over the intent scheduling, you can also set the alarms yourself in when the service is finished with updating the widget, and supply `RTC` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME` as the type of alarms. Both types won't wake up the device if it's sleeping. If the device is not sleeping (but locked) you'll effectively piggy back on other events that woke the device.

If you really need to update as soon as the device is unlocked, the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) broadcast might be what you need, but I'd still recommend to implement that as an addition to scheduling a periodic update.

Comment: The thing is, I have to have the service running. Because I have a  countdowntimer in there, that updates the widget every second. I know it maybe doesn't sound good but that's just how I have to do... Shouldn't it be possible to use AlarmManager and then repeat every second? But I'm not sure if that is quite good, because it just doesn't update, it does other stuff too. 

But I realized that when the service stopped, the user can just resize the widget and the service will start again, exactly as it would stay on.

Comment: Hard one, it's not the best use case for a widget, a widget isn't really designed to update that fast. The service will start when a user interacts with the widget, but if you are using an IntentService it would stop when the work is done. In your case it doesn't make much sense since you'll be updating every second anyway even if the widget isn't visible. Catching ACTION_USER_PRESENT sounds like your only option, but I'm not sure if you can declare that in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is Possible!

When the user turn off the screen You Have to handle `BroadCast Receiver` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

- That handle to Stop service  & the service stops and stop to update the widget,
- when the user wake up the device you have to Receive Broadcast start to update the widget.

I think it would be The best idea to save more battery.

For More information Please Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up/4541982#4541982)