# Guide to create code to unlock device

Tags: android, locking, android-sensors, unlock

I am developing an sensor based app to unlock & lock device using sensors. 
I am able to lock the device using Device Administrator API.

But, Unfortunately I am unable to find any code to unlock the screen programmatically. I have searched over Google & other Android Development sites too.
Then, too I didn't find any solution.

Tried several tricks like wakelock but it doesn't work for some devices & eats battery
Then, I tried KeyguardManager but it removes the lockscreen but not does not unlock the device

I am trying to use Receiver for receive screen on/off events but I don't know how to make
it

Hope, Any one can help me

I already had thorough search but no hopes

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up/4541982#4541982) will resolve your problem. You need to make use of PowerManager.

Comment: Use Handler & send empty delayed message method.
For Samsung ROMS set the Timeout of WAKELOCK.AQUIRE(LONG>0)
For other AOSP ROMS set the WAKELOCK.AQUIRE(0)