# Android service do operation after delay during deep sleep

Tags: android, multithreading, service, wakelock

I have a broadcast receiver that runs on boot and launches a service that will wait a delay via Thread.sleep() and then perform an operation.

It works while my phone screen is on, but when the delay is > 30 seconds and the screen is off my phone goes to sleep and the service is paused during deep sleep.

Do I need to request a wakelock for this or can I schedule a thread to run after a certain delay and wake the phone up?

Comment: Maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up
?

Comment: just as a side note be aware that this will drain the battery life drastically and google also does not recommend it.

Comment: I'm aware wakelocks drain the battery. Im wondering if there's an alternative. My application requires this feature.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Alarms seems perfect for this thanks