# Java Android service keep device awake to receive serial port commands

Tags: java, android, serial-port, wakelock

I am creating a car computer with a tablet (Asus MemoPad ME572C).
I have an arduino connected with the tablet through an usb to serial adapter. Now i need to be able to turn the screen on from standby.

What i tried is putting this in the oncreate of an activity

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON        
);
```

This is working but if i leave the tablet for a minute or so turned into standby, i can't wake it anymore.
It looks like the tablet has stopped my service or just doesn't listen on the serial port.

I don't know how to debug this or solve it. Hope you can help.

PS: sorry my english isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the method your using (WindowManager.LayoutParams flags) your activity needs to be fullscreen.

If that doesn't work try [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179932/4138037)
It's a depreciated method, so you don't want to keep it long-term.

Quoting from @Yar:

> To wake up the screen:
>
> ```
> PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
> WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK |
> ```
>
> PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP),
>   "TAG");
>       wakeLock.acquire();
>
> To release the screen lock:
>
> ```
> KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
> KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
> keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
> ```
>
> And the manifest needs to contain:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
> ```
>
> For more details about PowerManager, refer to the API documentation:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

If that doesn't work you'll need to investigate whether the service is being shut down. You should be able to prevent that happening by calling `startForeground()` on your service. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) for explanation and sample code.