# How to wake up the device

Tags: android

In my alarm Receiver class the device wake up and make phone call.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:07026762692"));
     phoneIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(phoneIntent);
   ................
   ................
```

The device does not wake up with my own activiy

```
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NoteActivity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

But, when I press press lock button on device, this activity is showed.
How can I do to unlock the device and show my activity.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up

Comment: Some thing about PendingIntent.