# How to wake up device from power safe in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, android-wake-lock

Hy everyone,

How to wake up device from power safe mode??

For example, i have a background service that have a alarm manager that start at determinated clock.

I would like to wake up device from power safe mode (in power safe mode, the device turn off the screen).

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake Android Device up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up)